# Access vba CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a procedure in my Access that will create query strings based off of records held within a database record set. However when the string is passed to a QueryDef an error is generated saying

Run-time error '3131':
Syntax error in FROM clause.

However I have tested adding the query manually and there is no syntax issues.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Q7 
FROM EXP01_PRODUCTO_ER AS NEW LEFT JOIN LOCAL_EXP01_PRODUCTO_ER AS OLD ON
((NEW.PRER_IDEMPR = OLD.PRER_IDEMPR)
AND
(NEW.PRER_CODPROD = OLD.PRER_CODPROD)
AND
(NEW.PRER_CODSPROD = OLD.PRER_CODSPROD)
AND
(NEW.PRER_COESTREF = OLD.PRER_COESTREF)
AND
(NEW.PRER_FECOMVAV = OLD.PRER_FECOMVAV)
AND
(NEW.PRER_FEFINVAV = OLD.PRER_FEFINVAV)
AND
(NEW.PRER_FECALDB2 = OLD.PRER_FECALDB2)
AND
(NEW.PRER_USUMOD = OLD.PRER_USUMOD)
AND
(NEW.PRER_FECMOD = OLD.PRER_FECMOD)
AND
(NEW.PRER_INCONSUL = OLD.PRER_INCONSUL))
WHERE 
(OLD.PRER_IDEMPR IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_CODPROD IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_CODSPROD IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_COESTREF IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_FECOMVAV IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_FEFINVAV IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_FECALDB2 IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_USUMOD IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_FECMOD IS NULL
AND
OLD.PRER_INCONSUL IS NULL);
```

Procedure:

```
Sub AltQrys()
  Dim db As Database, RST As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer, _
      QrySelect, QryWhere, QryName As String, _
      s, t As Integer
  Set db = CurrentDb
  tblName = "tblFields"
  Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & tblName, dbOpenDynaset)
  '# COUNT FIELDS IN FIELD TABLE
  fldcnt = RST.Fields.Count
  '# MOVE TO FIRST RECORD OF FIELDS TABLE
  RST.MoveFirst
  '# ASSIGN FIELD RECORD VALUES TO ARRAY
  Dim Q As Variant
  ReDim Q(0 To fldcnt - 1)
  t = 1
  Do While RST.EOF = False And t < 299
    For i = 0 To fldcnt - 1
      Q(i) = RST(i)
    Next i
    QryName = Q(5) & "_ALT_" & Q(2)
    '# CREATE QUERY SRTINGS AND NAME
    QrySelect = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Q" & Q(5) & " FROM EXP01_" & Q(2) & " AS NEW LEFT JOIN LOCAL_EXP01_" & Q(2) & " AS OLD JOIN ON "
    QryWhere = " WHERE "

    '# LOOP CONCATENATE FIELD VALUES IN QUERY STRING
    '# START AT COLUMN 6 UNTIL COLUMN VALUE IS NULL
    s = 6
    Do While Q(s) <> "" And s < fldcnt
      QrySelect = QrySelect & "(NEW." & Q(s) & " = OLD." & Q(s) & ") AND " & vbCrLf
      QryWhere = QryWhere & "OLD." & Q(s) & " IS NULL AND " & vbCrLf
      s = s + 1
    Loop
    QrySelect = Left(QrySelect, Len(QrySelect) - 7)
    QryWhere = Left(QryWhere, Len(QryWhere) - 7)
    QryWhole = QrySelect & QryWhere & ";"
    '# SEE STRING !!!!
    'MsgBox QryWhole
    '# CREATE QUERY DEFS WITH NAME AND STRING
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef QryName, QryWhole

    Debug.Print CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QryName).Properties(4).Value        
    '# MOVE TO NEXT RECORD
    RST.MoveNext
    Debug.Print t
    t = t + 1
  Loop
  Set RST = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see NEW or OLD in lists of reserved words in Access SQL, but it still sounds like trouble. Try replacing them with e.g. `tNew` and `tOld`.

Comment: What line gves you the error? How did you test it manually - did you debug.print QryWhole and copy/paste into Query SQL window?

Comment: @dbmitch Error is at line **CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef QryName, QryWhole**. This also happens when trying to assign the QryWhole string value to CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QryName).Properties(4).Value if the QueryDef already exists. I copy and pasted the query into a Query object in the database and it ran fine.